is it possible to add virtual users to the same domain as local users on postfix
Is it actually possible to add virtual users (sqlite) to a postfix server working with local users with ONLY ONE domain?

local users with maildir=$HOME/mail/
virtual users with maildir=/var/vmail/$USER/

The whole system is in place, the sqlite base, the *.cf of postfix. Everything works perfectly in dovecot, but for postfix, I never manage to make the 2 systems work together.
So before continuing to spend hours for nothing, I would like to know if what I am trying to do is possible.

Yes, it's definitely possible to set up Postfix like this. I don't know if it's possible to set up Dovecot so it will use two different directory schemes for "local" and "virtual" mailboxes simultaneously.

@NikitaKipriyanov with ONLY ONE domain? I can't find how. Do you have some link? No problem with Dovecot. I already have it working this side.

Some domains can be made local (and the mailbox names will be shared, so if both a.example.com and b.example.org are local, user@a.example.com and user@b.example.org will be mapped to the same mailbox), while other domains can be made virtual, whose users won't clash. You can't have that within a single domain: it's either virtual or local in its entirety. You can use aliases to simulate that, though; setup virtual_alias_maps so several virtual addresses will be mapped to some local domain, or vice versa, alias_maps to map some local names to some virtual domain.

My suggestion is to not go that path. I prefer my mail systems to only use virtual domains for end users; the local names aren't used for normal mail at all; instead they are used only for "protocol" mail. That way it is easier to manage things. In your case I'd go as far as redesign and migrate the existing system to this more symmetric and coherent scheme.
